# workspaces broken with latest update (1/28/2013)?

Tags: ros, catkin, setup.bash, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a rosbuild workspace overlayed on top of a catkin workspace according to [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin). I *only* source the rosbuild workspace setup.bash in my ~/.bashrc.

The release repository was updated today, and I upgraded my packages. It seems like my existing workspaces broke until I reinitialized them. I didn't think to capture the output before re-initializing.

Can someone confirm that this problem exists? Or did I just experience a weird hiccup?

**Edit#1**

Never mind, updates on a second machine worked correctly. This was a machine specific issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53573/workspaces-broken-with-latest-update-(1/28/2013)?/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-29**:
I tried to upgrade my Precise Groovy development system this morning, but there were a long list of packages being kept back. Maybe that caused your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect this bug report (which has been fixed since) was the cause. https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/329

As far as I can tell, reinitializing the workspaces is sufficient.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1